# Extract character from db to another db with all items

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

I tried to copy the data related to the guid of a character to another db (same account) but it always appears without any item

I am use deleted/insert

This from inventori db for example:

```
DELETE FROM `character_inventory` WHERE `item`=item;
INSERT INTO `character_inventory` VALUES (guid, bag, slot, item);
```

Ever export/import the character appear without items: no equiment and no inventory

psd: I executed the query with the server turned off and on with the same result

Comment: That `INSERT` query is not in the correct form. Double-check your syntax.

Comment: @tadman its only EXAMPLE the  delete/insert its 4k lines approximately and i replace values for name columns.
the problem is for character is all imported fine but 0 items in inventory and equiment.

I tink so is no necesary add all tables or querrys used. ?

Comment: What I mean is there's no values here, that's a column specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to import the table content from another database.

```
INSERT INTO db1.`character_inventory` SELECT * FROM db2.`character_inventory` WHERE guid=XXX;
```

You need also to copy the **item_instance** table probably, so use:

```
INSERT INTO db1.`item_instance` SELECT * FROM db2.`item_instance`;
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefano but this is for inset all table, y only need insert/update especifer character/guid. What would the querry be in this case?

Comment: you can add WHERE condition in the SELECT query to insert/update a specific character/guid